# Other Alternatives to Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using cookies to store data at client end for later access. But my concern is I am unable to set more than 20 cookies and I am looking for alternative to cookies.
Please help me on this

```
 Updated
```

I found jStorage plugin [here](http://www.jstorage.info/) But it does not work for me in this case..

Comment: Just store them all in session or some DB in the server side and reference it by 1 cookie?

Comment: Are you sure you need to store this much data on the client side? Have you considered using (long-lasting) server side sessions and storing the data in there?

Comment: What about to create and manipulate an `xml` file on client-side ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can leverage local/session storage of HTML5

To save a value:

```
localStorage.name = "Bob";
```

To get a value:

```
alert(localStorage.name);
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

Answer (score 3):

The two main options are [Web Storage and Web SQL Database](http://caniuse.com/#search=storage).

Comment: "The Web SQL Database specification is no longer being maintained and support may be dropped in future versions." http://caniuse.com/#search=storage

Answer (score 2):

Are you storing one piece of information in each cookie? Because you could use [JSON serialization](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-json-serialization/) to store more data in each individual cookie.

Comment: It needs to be mentioned that Cookie size is limited to 4KB. That 4KB include all the header information and cookie name, so basically cookie value is limited to somewhere about 4000 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There are few alternatives to cookies

1. Session (server side)
2. If HTML5 compliant browser then you can even have client side database

Comment: Hidden fields? What does it have to do with long-term data storage?

Comment: (+1) Thanks Max for correcting. I have updated. My initial understanding was Sol wanted a storage mechanism. Hidden fields can not be shared between web pages.

Comment: [The Web SQL Database specification is no longer being maintained and support may be dropped in future versions.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage)

Answer (score -3):

You can store only one cookie representing a session ID (for example, an alfanumeric randomly generated long string). Then you just need a database to store all your data (that now is on 20 cookies) together with that session ID. At runtime, you read from the only cookie the session ID, and load from the DB all data.

Comment: The question is asking about storing data on the client. Sessions require the data to be stored on the server.